# How to receive an email alert if particular event occur in iOS app

Tags: ios

We have multiple iOS apps live in Apple App Store. We want to receive email  notification as soon as any critical event occur in our app. We are using Crashlytics SDK and it notifies us whenever the app crashes but there are other scenarios where we want to receive email notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to achieve this is making API call & from backend you can get email for particular event. Its because Apple doesn't allow to send email without opening the default Mail Picker.

Other options is, Integrate any third party analytics & using which you can do coding for registering the event. Then you will get that event registered at backend for your review.

Awesome third party analytics, [Google Analytics](https://www.google.co.in/analytics/), [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com), [MixPanel](https://mixpanel.com)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes we are using Flurry and Google Analytics and it's being used to track the events. However we need immediate email notification as soon as any critical event occur so we can take corrective measures immediately. Google Analytics offers Custom Alerts but we get the Email Digest on Daily/Weekly/Monthly interval.

Comment: Flurry's email alerts are found from Manage -> Alerts on the application screen. The alert is always sent to the email address you are signed in with (ie they are per user, not company wide). You can create an account using the email address of a group if you need the alerts sent to multiple people.

Comment: Thanks Flurry Support. It was the best solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Till now the best SDKs I've used are [NewRelic](http://newrelic.com/mobile-monitoring) & [Segment](https://segment.com/) both are awesome & different !! You should surely check them once. Easy to integrate and will show you everything you need from your app. This is just from my personal experience.